# What is the meaning of this " ones short leaves in war"?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

> "Perhaps all this is merely a legacy from ones short leaves in the war" is an excerpt from "big four" by agatha christie

"Ones short leaves in war " in the big four by agatha christie

Comment: Please give more context

Comment: Note that you had the quote wrong.  You missed the word "the".  It is very important to give lots of context and check that you have the quote exactly  correct. Please now check that you have the quote correct.  I suspect that it should be "one's" with an apostrophe.  This matters. We still want more context: Who says this. Who are they speaking to?

Comment: Also Agatha Christie was an English author, and this is from a book (a written document) so your tags "American English" and "Spoken English" are misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The context of the full quotation helps here.

Hastings is crossing the Channel, from France to England, and can't relax on the boat, instead saying "from the moment I get on board, I feel that the time is too short to settle down to anything."

Then he tries to explain how he feels.

> Perhaps all this is merely a legacy from one's short leaves in the war, where it seemed a matter of such importance to secure a place near the gangway, and be one of the first to disembark lest one should waste precious minutes of one's three or five days' leave.

"Leaves" is being used as a noun, meaning being away from work, rather than the things on trees. During the war, men fighting abroad would come home on their leaves to see their family and friends. Hastings was an Army officer in World War I and would have fought on the Western front, crossing the Channel to return home.

Hastings is saying that men had to make the most of every single minute of their leave/holiday during the war because they weren't home for very long, and he still feels like that when he's repeating that journey back to England that he made during the war.